# how can a developing country improve its infrastructure?

Tags: development-economics, infrastructure

Developing countries have poor infrastructure, I know, but how can it increase its quality? Receiving aid is a solution that pops to mind first but are there any other solutions? I know that some countries can attract FDI and improve their infrastructure but I think that's only when that firm gets something in return like natural minerals. Pretty sure China has attracted lots of FDI because it has large reserves of mineral but what if a county has nothing to offer in terms of natural resources?

Comment: Welcome to Economics:SE. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, [we expect questions to provide evidence of prior research](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help), and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Fundamentally, someone has to go to that country and build it, or the people in that country have to build it.